# Why do my C++ (SDL) programs receive 60ms of lag every 3000ms?

Tags: c++, process, sdl

My simple C++ application (which uses SDL) lags by ~60ms every ~3000ms. Using VSYNC at 144hz, the lag occurs exactly every 425 frames (~3000ms). At 144hz, my frame time should be approximately ~7ms every frame. Every 425th frame (or ~3000ms), my frame time is ~60ms.

I first noticed the lag just my moving a square around the screen using keyboard input - I could feel a stutter/jump every few seconds. When I began to output my deltaTime with a timestamp/frame count to the console, I noticed that the lag was very consistent (~60ms) and occurred very consistently (~3000ms, or every 425 frames at 144hz with VSYNC).

I have tried disabling VSYNC, running my application in fullscreen, in windowed mode, etc. Without VSYNC, the frame time for each lag is variable, but the time of ~3000ms remains the same. I have tried running other applications on my computer (video games) to see if the lag was noticeable there and it was not.

I have tried uninstalling my antivirus, but the lag is still there. I have tried closing down other Apps using Task Manager with no change. I have tried closing down a few Background Processes but I am not really sure what I should be closing, and I have not tried closing down any Windows Processes using Task Manager because I wasn't sure what might cause instability.

I am using the following code to track my deltaTime in the console. I am implementing this code within the main loop (while !quit) of Lazy Foo's (https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/) tutorial #8. I added keyboard movement and VSYNC, but I do not think this is making a difference because I also tried the following deltaTime tracking code within his tutorial #2 and the lag time was the same (~60ms every ~3000ms).

Note: I am only outputting deltaTime information if the deltaTime for that frame is over 10ms just to keep a clean console output. Before I did this it looked like most of my other deltaTimes were around 7ms.

```
// Initialize tracking variables at the top of the file
Uint64 NOW = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
Uint64 LAST = 0;
double deltaTime = 0;
int frameCounter = 0;
int lastDeltaSpikeFrame = 0;
double timeCounter = 0;
double lastDeltaSpikeTime = 0;

// Use them in the application loop
while( !quit )
{
    LAST = NOW;
    NOW = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
    deltaTime = (double)((NOW - LAST) * 1000 / (double)SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency());

    frameCounter++;
    timeCounter += deltaTime;

    if (deltaTime > 10)
    {
        int frameChangeSinceLastSpike = frameCounter - lastDeltaSpikeFrame;

        double timeChangeSinceLastSpike = timeCounter - lastDeltaSpikeTime;

        printf("deltaTime = %f\ntimeCounter = %f\ntimeChangeSinceLastSpike = %f\nframeCounter = %i\nframeChangeSinceLastSpike = %i\n\n\n", deltaTime, timeCounter, timeChangeSinceLastSpike, frameCounter, frameChangeSinceLastSpike);

        lastDeltaSpikeFrame = frameCounter;
        lastDeltaSpikeTime = timeCounter;

// Rest of the application code...
```

Here is the console output (past the 2nd frame, lag timing of ~60ms every ~3000ms becomes consistent):

```
deltaTime = 308.039800
timeCounter = 308.039800
timeChangeSinceLastSpike = 308.039800
frameCounter = 1
frameChangeSinceLastSpike = 1


deltaTime = 66.737300
timeCounter = 374.777100
timeChangeSinceLastSpike = 66.737300
frameCounter = 2
frameChangeSinceLastSpike = 1


deltaTime = 60.252300
timeCounter = 3369.369500
timeChangeSinceLastSpike = 2994.592400
frameCounter = 426
frameChangeSinceLastSpike = 424


deltaTime = 59.695400
timeCounter = 6368.786900
timeChangeSinceLastSpike = 2999.417400
frameCounter = 851
frameChangeSinceLastSpike = 425


deltaTime = 59.917200
timeCounter = 9369.138700
timeChangeSinceLastSpike = 3000.351800
frameCounter = 1276
frameChangeSinceLastSpike = 425


deltaTime = 60.112800
timeCounter = 12369.418100
timeChangeSinceLastSpike = 3000.279400
frameCounter = 1701
frameChangeSinceLastSpike = 425
```

... the lag time (60ms) occurs every ~3000 ms and exactly 425 frames beyond this point.

Comment: I would start by testing it on another computer.

Comment: Try running a profiler

Comment: Is this a Release / optimized build?